# Regex to remove scheme (http:) for a URL

Tags: regex

I have never used regex before and I have been asked to remove the scheme from a URL. this would make it to transform the URL from http://www.foo.com to //www.foo.com.

I was just wondering whether this was possible? and to know if anyone knew any tutorials or website which will help me with this as an absolute beginner.

Thanks for any help which you can give.

Comment: What made you think of using regexes? A URL parser would be significantly easier.

Comment: What language are you using?  Why not do a substring?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  If you never used regex before, then you need to learn.  What you're asking is trivial - search the web - there are millions of examples.  Oh, and the actual details will depend on the language.

Comment: Its for work and they have requested it this way even after explaining that I don't know regex and there are easier ways to do this. If there is any information which you can give to help I would be very greatful

Comment: Without outright giving you the answer, check out [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [alternations](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Is this only for http, or for [all possible variants of URLs?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with basic string manipulation, and I would recommend it over regex.

However if you insist on using regex, here's a regex which would do this if combined with regex replace of whichever language you are using:

```
^http:
^\   /
| \ /
|  `- Match this string literally
|
`- Match at start of string
```

If you're also going to remove `https:` it would look like this:

```
^https?:
^\  /^^^
| \/ |||
| |  ||`- Literally match `:`
| |  |`- Previous is optional (literal s)
| |  `- Literally match s
| `- Match this string literally
|
`- Match at start of string
```

These all assume you are only checking exact URLs, if you'd like to check anywhere in a string, you could replace the `^` anchor (beginnning of string) with `\b` which is for word boundary:

```
\bhttps?:
\/\  /^^^
|  \/ |||
|  |  ||`- Literally match `:`
|  |  |`- Previous is optional (literal s)
|  |  `- Literally match s
|  `- Match this string literally
|
`- Word boundary (typically whitespace, but also `][` and so on
```

Make the regex replace everything that matches that pattern with '' (empty string). I recommend adding a `i` flag for case-insensitive matching.

Here's a good tutorial site on regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: *"remove the scheme from a URL"* - There are [dozens of official schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) that might need to be replaced, not just `http`.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about `http` (see title). I included `https` since it is a "close relative".

Comment: `http` appears to have been offered as an example - see the title.

Comment: His example mentions the output should be `//www.foo.com` which would invalidate ~half of the schemes in your provided URL. Until he provides more information, I'll assume it's for http (and possibly https). Your point is of course valid tho, and I've asked him in the comments for clarification. As an aside, which other URL schemes than http and https use `//www.foo.com` to maintain the current protocol it is on?

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example in PHP:

```
 <?php

 $url = 'http://www.foo.com';
 $url = preg_replace('/^http:/i', '', $url);

 print "{$url}\n";
 ?>
```

Comment: I'll add this again - there are [dozens of official schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) that might need to be replaced, not just `http`.